# Is there a similar game making software to warcraft's world editor?

Tags: game-maker

Currently, warcaft's world editor is the only software which I know to use, I was wondering if there are other similar, but game making software out there? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are programs that are similar in ways... Maybe not "world editors" but if you don't mind learning some code then there are programs like Game Maker: Studio that has 3D capabilities now and that you can make entire worlds from scratch also, there is Unity which is what i think you maybe looking for more likely as it is mainly made to make 3D games so it works well... Now both you will need to learn some coding but there are some shortcuts in Game Maker as in there are some drag and drop commands!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some engines that you may like:

[CryEngine](http://cryengine.com/) - Great Graphics, free version is no longer updated.

[Unreal Engine 4](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4) - Good Graphics, Easy to use, No limitations for free 
version.

[Unity 5](https://unity3d.com/) - Not as good graphics, VERY beginner friendly, pro version is now free.

Hope this helps. With each one you could make stuff with no coding. UE4 and CryEngine have drag and drop languages, whereas Unity 5 requires C# or JS. You would only have to use these, however, if you wanted to makes games compared to just enviroments.